# how to extract a phrase between 2 characters php?

Tags: php

```
$string="Quick {brown fox jump} over the {lazy dog.}Go back to the forest";
```

I want to exatract strings, covered by {} symbols, from above `$string`,using regular expression
I tried using `substr`, but it only give me the first occurrence
I'm completly beginer to PHP
please help me..

Comment: You could use preg_match_all to extract the sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$string="Quick {brown fox jump} over the {lazy dog.}Go back to the forest";
preg_match_all('/{([^}]+)}/',$string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);//$matches[1] contains array of all the matches in parenthesis
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => brown fox jump
    [1] => lazy dog.
)
```